# Appearance difference between Qt4 and Qt5

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I use Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. I installed Qt4 from Ubuntu repo.
Version is Qt 4.8.3 and Qt Creator 2.5.2

I also downloaded Qt5 from qt-project.org and its version number is
Qt 5.0.1 and Qt Creator 2.6.2

When I compiled and run same project, their appearance slightly different.
What is the reason for that? Is it because of Ubuntu or Qt5?

[image: Qt4 and Qt5 appearance difference]

Comment: I changed image. Qt4 looks more clear and sharp

Comment: Could be [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27106)...?

Comment: I did same thing on Windows 7 and Qt4 and Qt5 look exactly same.

Comment: The bug above is afaict reported on Linux only.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson you are right. I did not notice.

Answer (score 5):

Qt5 brought in some major changes of the GUI code, if you spot differences it's likely to be down to that rather than anything else.

> New graphics architecture. Qt 5 introduces a new graphics architecture for Qt Quick using Scenegraph on top of OpenGL. OpenGL (ES) 2.0 is mandated for this to work. The new architecture makes it easier to integrate OpenGL-based content, such as shader effects, with Qt Quick-based applications. The QWidget-based stack continues to work as in Qt 4.x (based on QPainter), but supported back-ends have been limited to SW rasterization, pixmaps, and images, an OpenGL backend for GL surface,s and a backend for PDF generation and printing. X11 and CoreGraphics are no longer supported.

From [Dr Dobbs Qt5 beta tour](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/qt-5-beta-a-developers-tour/240006976).